# PM2 restarting keystonejs app repetitively

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pm2, keystonejs

I am using throng to cluster my keystonejs application, which seems to work fine
but when I run

```
const throng = require("throng"),
      dotenv = require('dotenv');

(function usedotenv() {
    try {
        dotenv.config();
    }
    catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
    }
}());

throng({
  workers: process.env.WEB_CONCURRENCY || 1,
  grace: 4000,
  master() {
    console.log("Starting master node");
  },
  start(id) {
    console.log("Starting worker node "+id);
    require("./keystone");
  }
});
```

using `pm2 start index`

```
│ App name │ id │ mode    │ pid   │ status  │ restart │ uptime │ memory │ watching │
├──────────┼────┼─────────┼───────┼─────────┼─────────┼────────┼────────┼──────────┤
│ index    │ 0  │ cluster │ 11964 │ online  │ 29      │ 2s     │ 0 B    │ disabled │
│ index    │ 1  │ cluster │ 6260  │ online  │ 12      │ 2s     │ 0 B    │ disabled │
│ index    │ 2  │ cluster │ 7920  │ online  │ 12      │ 2s     │ 0 B    │ disabled │
│ index    │ 3  │ cluster │ 5260  │ online  │ 12      │ 1s     │ 0 B    │ disabled │
│ index    │ 4  │ cluster │ 15688 │ online  │ 21      │ 1s     │ 0 B    │ disabled │
│ index    │ 5  │ cluster │ 17204 │ online  │ 15      │ 1s     │ 0 B    │ disabled │
│ index    │ 6  │ cluster │ 15576 │ online  │ 22      │ 1s     │ 0 B    │ disabled │
│ index    │ 7  │ cluster │ 6012  │ online  │ 20      │ 1s     │ 0 B    │ disabled │
│ index    │ 8  │ cluster │ 10768 │ online  │ 32      │ 1s     │ 0 B    │ disabled │
│ index    │ 9  │ cluster │ 9460  │ online  │ 14      │ 0s     │ 0 B    │ disabled │
│ index    │ 10 │ cluster │ 16968 │ online  │ 32      │ 0s     │ 0 B    │ disabled │
│ index    │ 11 │ cluster │ 12688 │ online  │ 23      │ 0s     │ 0 B    │ disabled │
```

The website works fine, but pm2 keeps restarting the apps because they're not using any memory: `[PM2][WORKER] Process 0 restarted because it uses 0 memory and has ONLINE status`

How do I keep pm2 from restarting my apps?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like all of your processes are named the same "index". If you use

```
pm2 start 4
```

for example to start just the the one process does it stop the restarting of all process's?

I am just wondering if using the id to start it will allow it to identify just the single index, instead of all of the processes named index

Comment: When I start the process with an id it still restarts